# Python automate Image label

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm using Pyro to indentify custom objects in an Image. I want to evaluate the performance of the model by comparing it with the Ground truth. To generate the ground truth, I wanted to automate the process by drawing bounding box around the image(using my model) and letting the user correct the bounding box to help save time. For each bounding box I want to have a label, sub label, group the same lables and decription. What would be the best way to do this ? LabelImg dosen't give an option of sublabels and decription.

I have trained my model to draw bounding boxes around images

```
from detecto import core, utils, visualize

model = core.Model.load(r'..\Downloads\model_weights.pth', ['Person', 'Dog', 'Cat'])

image = utils.read_image('13.jpg')
predictions = model.predict(image)

# predictions format: (labels, boxes, scores)
labels, boxes, scores = predictions
print(labels,scores)
print(boxes)

visualize.show_labeled_image(image, boxes, labels)
```

Now I want to automate the manual labelling process of the images by using the same algorithm. I want to draw boundry boxes around objects and let user provide label, sub label, description and group the labels. Basically, I want to speed up the manual labelling process by using my model to pre label the objects and let users make modification to the boundry boxes and add the above metnioned details to the labels

Comment: Your question seems somewhat vague. Please provide the code you have so far, and a precise example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: @AdrienF Updated my question with more details!